# Can I drop a power from my basis and still get convergence in the mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

If I start with the set of powers of $x$ excluding $x^2$, that is $\{1, x, x^3, x^4 \dots\}$ and perform Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization in the interval $-1 \le x \le 1$, will the resulting basis still produce convergence in the mean for a well-behaved function?

"Obviously"  I cannot match term-for-term any polynomial expression that involves $x^2$, since it is not in my basis, but given the set of basis functions $Q_n(x)$ from the above process and any reasonable function $f(x)$, does
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\sum_n\, (Q_n,f)\,\,  Q_n(x)  - \, f(x) \right|^2 =0
$$
that is, we can approximate $f(x)$ in the mean?

I had thought that the answer was "no", but numerical evidence is against me, and I can't find a function that is "unexpandable" in this basis.

Comment: If your function has a Taylor polynomial with your interval $[-1,1]$ within the radius of convergence of the Taylor polynomial, then changing the basis, will still give you a different representation of the same polynomial, and yes, it will approximate $f(x)$

Comment: The inner product is $$\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx$$ (or a constant times that, and if only real-valued functions are considered, ignore the conjugation)? And the space under consideration is $L^2([-1,1])$ or $C([-1,1])$?

Comment: If that is the case, the [Müntz–Szász theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCntz%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A1sz_theorem) implies that you still obtain an ONB. In fact, you can drop a lot more powers. You must keep the constant, and a set $S$ of exponents $\geqslant 1$ such that $$\sum_{n \in S} \frac{1}{n} = +\infty.$$